# How to defined layers by viewport on EyeShot?

Tags: eyeshot

I have a common eyeshot model (with entities) with multiple layers, i want to display multiple viewports and set which layers have to be visible. As i understand, layers are defined by model and not viewport ?
Best regards.

Comment: Yes, that's so, layers collection belongs to model. What is your goal?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question or problem.  Could you add more description to what you are trying to do and what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could do the trick.  Let me know!
Take out the regen and invalidate if you aren't looking to update the viewport instantly.

```
public void makeLayerVisible(ref ViewportLayout vp, string layerName)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < vp.Entities.Count; i++)
  {
    if (vp.Entities[i].LayerName == layerName)
    {
      vp.Entities[i].Visible = true;
    }
  }
  vp.Entities.Regen();
  vp.Invalidate();
}


public void makeLayerHidden(ref ViewportLayout vp, string layerName)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < vp.Entities.Count; i++)
  {
    if (vp.Entities[i].LayerName == layerName)
    {
      vp.Entities[i].Visible = false;
    }
  }
  vp.Entities.Regen();
  vp.Invalidate();
}
```